# Live USB wifi problem

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, live-usb

I am using an HP laptop with Windows 10. I just created a 14.04 LTS live USB and booted in nicely. I was able to connect to my SKY broadband WIFI without any problems. The installation also went ahead smoothly. HOWEVER, at the last installation point, it said grub2 installation failed and terminated the process. I read around and booted in again to fix this by installing grub manually. This is when things started became funny.

I could no longer connect to the wifi network. I can see the network but it doesn't connect to the network. I have gone through the usual debugging stuff like rfkill and what not. I can also see that the kernel modules are loaded. Besides, it connected properly before, so everything needed for it should be loaded. ALso, I have tried, forgetting the network and trying again.

This has left me really baffled. Is the problem on the router's end? Any help will be welcome.

Comment: have you tried another wifi network ?

Comment: Well, that is my home network. I don't have any other network. I am connected to it even now on windows 10. What is bizarre is that I was connected and ubuntu downloaded everything and installed it via that wifi network.

Answer (score 0):

A few things could have gone wrong when installing grub. Open a terminal Ctl + Alt + T.

Make sure that your grub settings are installed correctly 
'sudo update-grub'

Check pakages 
'sudo apt-get -f install'

Update.
'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Check latest kernels/ bugs

'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'

Reboot 
'sudo reboot'

Comment: Ah, to do anything like that, one would need a wifi connection, which is the point of the question.

Comment: You do not need wifi to run the first step. I would also edit your question with the the output of ' ifconfig' and any error messages from -f install.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Gigabyte mother board. Go into your bios, check if you have IOMMU disabled. Try enabling it, boot into ubuntu and check if you can connect to your network.